# How to return all Buckets from left table and return 0 when bucket from right table is null? (mysql)

Tags: mysql, left-join

I created a table with the needed buckets named `buckets` where there is a column named `mybuckets`.

I then created the following query:

```
SELECT 
 Id
,b.CityName
, SUM(Sales) as Sales
FROM buckets b
LEFT JOIN  production as t1 ON b.CityName = t1.CityName
group by
1,2
```

However, there are 9 buckets available but since this ID did not produce in 2 out of the 9 buckets available, only 7 buckets are returned.

How can I make sure that all buckets are showed and when there is no sale the value in the row is 0?

Here is an example of the tables

`Production`

[image]

`Buckets`

[image]

Results that I would like to get:

[image]

However, with the above query, the Production table is not returned because there is no production.

Comment: please add sample data and expected result

Comment: for example:  I want to know the sales for Paris, Rome, London. I want these cities to always appear in the dataset even if there are no sales. However, at present, cities with no production are not returned. Why?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You edited the query that you originally wrote in your post. It used to include:

```
...
WHERE ID IN (1)
...
```

Since the `ID` column is in the `production` table, this would filter out any rows where `production.ID` is NULL, due to the outer join. When you use any condition for a non-NULL value in the right table's columns of a left outer join, it eliminates the cases where there is no matched row.

Now that you removed that condition in the `WHERE` clause, you get matching rows for each cityname. Where there is no matching row in `production`, you get NULL for the `ID` and for the `SUM()` result:

```
+------+-------------+-------+
| Id   | CityName    | Sales |
+------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | Rome        |    10 |
|    2 | Paris       |    20 |
|    3 | London      |    30 |
|    4 | New York    |    40 |
| NULL | Los Angeles |  NULL |
+------+-------------+-------+
```

If you want to have `SUM()` return 0 instead of NULL when there is no matching row, then use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT
 Id
,b.CityName
, COALESCE(SUM(Sales), 0) as Sales
FROM buckets b
LEFT JOIN  production as t1 ON b.CityName = t1.CityName
group by
1,2;

+------+-------------+-------+
| Id   | CityName    | Sales |
+------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | Rome        |    10 |
|    2 | Paris       |    20 |
|    3 | London      |    30 |
|    4 | New York    |    40 |
| NULL | Los Angeles |     0 |
+------+-------------+-------+
```

`COALESCE()` returns its first non-NULL argument.